# Saving logcat to a file using SAF in android 30

Tags: android, storage, logcat

I have been struggling to find a way which will save logcat to file using Scoped Access framework. I have gone through the below link
[SAF link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files), but no luck.

Till Android 10, I was using "requestLegacyExternalStorage" to make it work with the below code.

```
 public void createLogs() {
    if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        File appDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/c4cex");
        File logDirectory = new File(appDirectory + "/logs");

        File logFile = new File(logDirectory, "c4cex.txt");
        //File preLogonLogFile = new File(logDirectory, "preLogonLogs.txt");

        // create app folder
        if (!appDirectory.exists()) {
            appDirectory.mkdir();
        }
        // create log folder
        if (!logDirectory.exists()) {
            logDirectory.mkdir();
        }
        try {

            //  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f  " + logFile);
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile + " -r 2048 -n 4"); // -r amount of bits to write, -n amount of logs to rotate
            //preLogonLogFile.createNewFile();
            //Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + preLogonLogFile + " -r 2048 -n 5"); // -r amount of bits to write, -n amount of logs to rotate

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

After getting the logs in a file , I want to share it through email and hence SAF approach will only work as per the Android documents.

Comment: "I want to share it through email" -- use `FileProvider`, as shown [in the documentation for sharing files](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing). "SAF approach will only work" -- you can store the content in filesystem locations that your process can write to (e.g., `getFilesDir()`) and use `FileProvider`.

Comment: I am using email composer plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

Comment: Find some Cordova plugin that lets you share using `FileProvider`. If you cannot find such a plugin, I guess you need to write one. I have not used Cordova in a nearly a decade, and so I am not familiar with the current lineup of plugins. The particular plugin that you linked to appears to be unmaintained, as its code has not been updated in nearly three years.

Comment: the mentioned plugin link for emailing already uses FileProvider

Comment: Better:       `if (!logDirectory.exists()) {
            if ( !logDirectory.mkdirs()) return;
        }` . You only need one mkdirs() call. Not two times mkdir(). And always check return value and stop if false.

Comment: You can use the same code to create that file on Android 11. Well.. i see no reason that it should not work.

Comment: "the mentioned plugin link for emailing already uses FileProvider" -- it uses an out of date version from the Android Support Library, and that may cause problems with combined with other plugins. It also does not appear to call `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` for you, so you would need to do that somewhere in your code and supply that `Uri` to the plugin.

Comment: @blackapps, 'getExternalStoragePublicDirectory' wont be supported from Android 12. Also c4cex.txt not getting created inside logs file using the above approach.

Comment: Yes it is supported again. CommonsWare reported that already two times. Please try it. It was always supported only deprecated but it worked always.

Comment: Just tried that code on an Android 12 emulator and it works perfectly.

Comment: `Saving logcat to a file using SAF ...` I wonder why you did not mention that in `"logcat -f " + logFile + .....` you did not know how to use a SAF uri there. And otherwise i do not understand your SAF problem.

Comment: `"logcat -f " + logFile + ....` You write `logFile` but probably you need `logFile.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: @blackapps, uri is the issue. Also I could see c4cex.txt file getting generated when checking in Android Device file explorer but in real device, its not appearing

Comment: Of course it is there. Do you think Android Device Explorer is kidding?

Comment: My bad, i checked in the wrong device storage

Comment: I could only see dir c4cex-->logs --> empty, ideally it should contain c4c txt file also